# importXML from yahoo.com specific table : recentrly viewd

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula, yahoo-finance

google sheet,
url : `https://finance.yahoo.com`
trying to get with `IMPORTXML`, specific table, named : 'recently viewed' from this site .
I tried to get all tables with :

```
importXML("https://finance.yahoo.com","//table")
```

but got error:

> Imported Xml content can not be parsed.

tried also :
`importHTML("https://finance.yahoo.com","table",1)` (or other index table)
got empty data

Answer (score -1):

Recently viewed is user specific - for example when I load that page , it is empty for me - because I havent used yahoo in roughly a decade, but its blank whether im logged in or not, which means when you make the request from google sheets, your like a brand new user with no history. SO the table is empty.

Comment: I think it's not connecting to history , I see table elements from google DevTools, I tried also to use Xpath copy from Devtools, with no results in importXML

Comment: thats what I was saying, is there is no history to connect to - so theres no data to display

Comment: how I 'create' history so importXML will 'see' it ?

Comment: You can't. What exactly are you trying to extract? You can Just grab all of it and filter rather than only the history

Comment: site : https://finance.yahoo.com , to grab one or two table data with google script

Comment: Can you specify what data your trying to retrieve from those tables? The same information is available within other parts of the page or site, just not formatted in a table

Comment: for example the "table" : Trending Tickers